# Why am I not able to select some elements from a list filtered by elements in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have a dataset in which, among other columns, there's 3 columns called `CLASS`, `DURATION` and `GENDER`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
CLASS = data['CLASS']
DURATION = data['DURATION']
GENDER = data['GENDER']
```

`CLASS` contains 5 types of entries - `blank, 1, 2, 3, 4`; `DURATION` contains either `-1` (that signifies some semantic value) or some positive integer; and `GENDER` contains either `M` or `F`. I am able to select the entries in `CLASS` by `GENDER` like so:

```
CLASS[GENDER=='M']
```

But I am not able to select entries in `OCCUP_CLASS` for durations of `-1` like so:

```
CLASS[DURATION=='-1']
```

Why is that? This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-604aed5ebca4> in <module>()
----> 1 CLASS[DURATION=='-1']

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    621         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    622         try:
--> 623             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    624 
    625             if not is_scalar(result):

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2558         try:
   2559             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2560                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2561         except KeyError as e1:
   2562             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: False
```

Comment: Is it possible that the key `-1` is an integer, not a string?

Comment: I tried `CLASS[DURATION==-1` as well, but I get the same error.

Comment: can you `print(CLASS)` what do you have there ?

Comment: There are 102008 rows in the dataset, so I cannot show the full output here. But like I said, `CLASS` contains either blanks or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

Comment: u can try `CLASS[DURATION>0]`

Comment: @Roushan with that, I get this error: `TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
`

Comment: ` CLASS[DURATION].astype(int)>0`

Comment: @Roushan Hmmm... this time its `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: OK then u can fill nan value to 0 or negative number, check the below answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce but u can try out

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
CLASS = data['CLASS']
DURATION = data['DURATION']
GENDER = data['GENDER']

# fill the nan value 
DURATION.fillna(0,inplace=True)
# using astype convert the value to int then compare
CLASS[DURATION].astype(int)>0
```

Comment: `DURATION.fillna(0,inplace=True)` gives the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fillna'`

Comment: why it is type if list , it should be of type panda Series, do u casting anywhere

Comment: Nope, I have done nothing apart from what I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe best to not split them up as Series to begin with and instead try this on the Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
data.loc[data['GENDER'] == 'M', 'CLASS']
data.loc[data['DURATION'] == -1, 'CLASS']
```